# Filtering data by date range

Tags: django, django-filter

I have my payment model I what to be able to select by date

```
class LeasePayment(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    amount  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    lease = models.ForeignKey(Lease)
    leaseterm = models.ForeignKey(LeaseTerm)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField()
    method = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='Ch',
                              choices=PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES)
```

Basically I want to be able to input 2 dates and display all the data between them . Righ now I started to implement this solution https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-filter/lbi_B4zYq4M based on django_filter. However since the task is pretty trivial was wondering if there an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [date__range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range) it will return data from database in selected date interval:

```
LeasePayment.objects.filter(payment_date__range=[start_date, end_date])
```